# quartz scheduler using QuartzInitializerServlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, quartz-scheduler

I came across all the examples of quartz 2.x, but I am not getting one definite example of how to initialize the quartz scheduler using Quartz Initializer Servlet.

Every one declaring a Servlet and writing some thing in a property file.
But No one is telling how to use this Quartz Initializer Servlet.

How can I configure my scheduler and when to call the start method of scheduler, I am asking this question particularly because I read in some blogs that even though we did not call start method explicitly, the servlet will take care of calling it!!
Is it true?
Can anyone explain clearly with example by taking a sample job, rather than copy pasting the quartz.properties from google

Because there are so many unanswered questions for this topic?

Sorry if I spelled anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

hi quartz is awesome library but there are very few examples regarding how to implement on web project.most of the example are on spring but they are too complex.So after much trial and error i finally able to implement quartz scheduler in my web application.I have tried Quartz RamJobStore,XmlJob(storing jobs and triggers in xml file) and Persistent job (storing job and trigger in mysql database). The best thing about quartz is for these three different approach i don't have to do anything extra i mean job and trigger creation logic remains the same for all these three approach however we just need to configure our properties files to make it work.

So i had implement quartz in java web application. I use net-beans ide.Below is the code to get you started.In this example i am using jdbcjobstore that mean i am creating job and trigger and store them in MySQL so that even if my system restarts job and trigger will be available as they are saved in persistent storage (MySQL).

1> First I created simple java web project in net-beans.

2> Add all jars in lib folder from "quartz-2.2.1" package  which i downloaded from there website in your net-beans project and MySQL connector jar also.

3> Configure log4j : to do that create log4j.properties file and add following lines :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.quartz=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

** Place this log4j.properties file in :

```
NetBeansProjects
    ->QurtzWebApp
        ->src
            ->java
                ->MySomePackage
                    ->HelloWorldJob.java
                log4j.properties
                quartz.properties
```

4> Create HelloWorldJob class by clicking right clicking on `source packages` in project hierarchy tree in net-beans project window.

My HelloWorldJob class Conatains Below Code :

```
package MySomePackage;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HelloWorldJob implements Job {
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)throws JobExecutionException {   
        try
        {
            String content = "Quartz 2 example @ ["+new Date()+"]";
            File file = new File("C:\\DemoMsg.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
               file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ex = "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Above code just create DemoMsg text file in c drive if already not created and write message define in content variable at defined trigger interval.for eg if i created trigger to execute after every 5 mins then you should see this message after every 5 min interval in text file.I purposely added date value so that you can verify whether file is written according to trigger schedule in this case after every 5 min.

5>Create `quartz.properties` file in location specify at 3 step and write below code in it :

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MY_SCHEDULER
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 4
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = MyDataStore
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false

org.quartz.dataSource.MailDataStore.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.MailDataStore.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.MailDataStore.user = yourdbusername
org.quartz.dataSource.MailDataStore.password = yourdbpassword
org.quartz.dataSource.MailDataStore.maxConnections = 20
```

Create quartz database in mysql and create quartz tables.Code for table creation will be found at `quartz-2.2.1\docs\dbTables\tables_mysql.sql` directory.Just import this sql file.

5> create web.xml file and add follwing entry :

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

6> Then created simple jsp page with tables and form which just accept jobid jobname cro expression from user and post it to another page.

7> Code for jsp file where form details are posted are as follows :

```
    type=request.getParameter("type");

    if(type.equals("createSchedule"))
    {
        String jobName="",jobDesc="",jobData="",cronVal="";

        jobName=request.getParameter("txtJobName");
        jobDesc=request.getParameter("txtJobDesc");
        jobData=request.getParameter("txtJobData");
        cronVal=request.getParameter("txtCronExrp");

        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
        System.out.println("------- Initialization Complete --------");

        System.out.println("------- Intitalizing Jobs ----------------");

        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(""+jobName, "JobGroupName");
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloWorldJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("jobData",""+jobData);
        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("jobDesc",""+jobDesc);

        System.out.println("------- Intitalizing Triggers ----------------");
        CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(""+jobName+"_"+"Trigger", "TriggerGroup").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(""+cronVal)).build();


        System.out.println("------- Starting Scheduler ----------------");

        JobKey jk=new JobKey(""+jobName);
        TriggerKey tk=new TriggerKey (""+jobName+"_"+"Trigger");
        JobDetail Searchjob = sched.getJobDetail(jk);
        System.out.println("Job found = " + Searchjob);

         //Check if job already exist
        if (Searchjob == null) // job not exist
        {
            Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            System.out.println(sched.getSchedulerName());
            System.out.println(jobDetail.getKey() + " has been scheduled to run at: " + ft+ " and repeat based on expression: " + trigger.getCronExpression() );

        } 
        else //job exist
        {
            sched.rescheduleJob(tk, trigger);
        }

        sched.start();

        %>Schedule Created Successfully !<%
    }
```

8> i pass parameter to check whether i want to create , edit or delete job.
for edition and deleting job you need job id which is defined while job creation.

I know answer is too long but i hope it will help you in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The QuartzInitializerServlet will start the scheduler for you, and place a StdSchedulerFactory in the ServletContext.

To retrieve the already-started scheduler:

```
ServletContext ctx = request.getServletContext();
StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getAttribute( QuartzInitializerServlet.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);  
Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
```

where "request" is the current HTTPServletRequest.

The scheduler can be configured with a "properties" file in the classpath or in WEB-INF (I didn't test this). The name of the configuration file must be specified in web.xml as a init-param of the QuartzInitializerServlet:

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>config-file</param-name>
         <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```